# UIView does not have member animateWithDuration?

Tags: ios, animation, swift, ios8

I'm making an iOS8 app and I am trying to animate one of the UIViews. I'm using Swift also. When I try to use the "animateWithDuration" method on my UIView that I created in Interface Builder and then used an IBOutlet to use it in code, Xcode gives me an error,

> 'UIView' does not have member named 'animateWithDuration'

The only framework I have imported is UIKit. Does anyone now why this isn't working?
When I say UIView.animateWithDuration I get no errors, but when I try to use the view I created in Interface Builder I get the error.

Comment: Can you, please, provide more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps your calling it wrong. It should be:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
    //changes to animate
})
```

That's how class methods are called in swift!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you a trying to call this method with instance of UIView subclass. But you shouldn't it is class method so use UIView(as Heliem said) and do your changes within its closure.

```
var myView:MyViewSubclass = MyViewSubclass()

UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: { () -> Void in
//changes to animate myView
     //to animate frame changes
     myView.Frame = newFrame

})
```